# Loading Angularjs from ASP MVC asynchornizly (AJAX) and execute them

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have created  ASP MVC Application , 
Inside I have created a Button to load HTML Data using Jquery Ajax Call , 
inside the HTML Data there is an angular expressions  but those angular expressions is not evaluated (executed) is shown as it is ,
so My question how can we execute Angular expression loaded using AJAX 
I understand we need to use $compile outside of Angular , so do I need to $compile outside Angular and how ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out and find the answer after research and more experimental : 
here is the solution 
after loading the dynamic HTML  (assuming using Ajax) 
I need to use $Compile and call $Apply outside angular see the demo below for more clarification  :

```js
var _app = angular.module("myapp",[]);
var _ctrl = _app.controller("myctrl", ['$scope','$window', function ($scope, $window) {
$scope.selectedFood = 1;

}])
 function add()
    {
        angular.injector(['ng']).invoke(['$compile', function ($compile) {
            
            var sel = 'div[ng-controller="myctrl"]';

            var _html = "<label>{{testing}}</label><select ng-model='selectedFood'   ><option value='0'>Banana</option><option value='1'>Apple</option><option value='2'>Orange</option><option value='3'>Tomato</option></select>";
            //angular.element(document.getElementById('test1')).scope().loaditems()
            var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("test1")).scope();
            
            $('#dvLoad').html($compile(_html)(scope));
            setTimeout(function(){ scope.$apply(); });
             
        }]);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" ng-app="myapp">
  <div id="test1" ng-controller="myctrl">

    <div id="dvLoad">
      Press the button to load Food List
      <input type="button" onclick="add();" value="Load" />
    </div>



  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, to use $compile you need a controller beacuase $compile needs $scope object.

for example:

```
angular.module('app',[])
.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$compile', function($scope, $compile){
     ...do stuff...
}])
```

Comment: ,This is just when I call from the controller itself , but my situation is to use $compile outside the controller even outside Angular .